# (How) can I increase the quota limit of LocalStorage in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, local-storage, quota

I need to increase the default quota limit of the LocalStorage in a Android WebView. Currently I can only use around 2.5MB. When trying to store more data, a `quota_exceeded_err (dom exception 22)` is raised.

Any ideas or do I have to switch to db/file system ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're talking about `HTML5 WebStorage` [`DOCS`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). (update 2023: [DOCS](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#introduction-15))

There is plenty of question on the same theme, only not *Android-specific*

- [HTML5 localStorage size limit for subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747285/html5-localstorage-restrictions-and-limits)
- [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/max-size-of-localstorage-values)
- [HTML5 LocalStorage size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500713/html5-localstorage-size)

Fact is, that HTML5 WebStorage suffers from different implementation on different platforms.
Desktop and Mobile Platforms & Browsers combinations differs in size of memory (disk space) quota assigned to each website (domain)

And no, you cannot increase/decrease space allocated for your HTML5 application, there is no such option in [`WebSettings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) as Android WebKit Settings Java accessor class, neither in WebKit implementation of HTML5 WebStorage as of now.

*citation:* http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space

> A mostly arbitrary limit of five megabytes per origin is recommended. Implementation feedback is welcome and will be used to update this suggestion in the future.

If you really need a large space in your HTML5 Application (no matter if it runs through PhonGap, Titanium, Rhodes or another...), I would strictly recommend you to use **[HTML Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)**

Even if the [DOCS](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) say:

> This document was on the W3C Recommendation track but specification work has stopped. The specification reached an impasse: all interested implementors have used the same SQL backend (Sqlite), but we need multiple independent implementations to proceed along a standardisation path.

The `Web SQL` is now only supported way on Android devices (which you do aim in this question) which allows you to increase/decrease space allocation for your data.

Please note the related question:

- [HTML5 IndexedDB, Web SQL Database and browser wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971813/html5-indexeddb-web-sql-database-and-browser-wars)

Comment: thx, I already knew most of this, but was hoping for a miracle ;)
so now I will have to switch my application to Web SQL DB ... so be it!

Comment: @NATOR sorry for not bringing out the miracle ;-)

Comment: Is there no way for the *user* to increase this limit?

Comment: @MarekSebera How do you actually "increase/decrease space allocation for your data."? This is my exact problem ATM in a hybrid web app. WebSettings seems to be the answer, but I am not sure how...

Comment: @oligofren read again, the answer is not WebSettings, but using WebSQL to store data instead of localStorage.

Comment: @MarekSebera I read that. And I meant WebSQL. In a normal Android web app the limit on WebSQL databases is approximately 8MB. Does this differ in a WebView?

Comment: "you cannot increase/decrease space allocated for your HTML5 application" is this the same case till now?

Comment: @venkatvb seems so, only thing relevant is, that instead of fixed storage quota, Android WebKit uses HTML5/JS automatic quota management, which should result in less problems with limited storage space. But WebSettings has methods. You can query current quota by `https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html#getQuotaForOrigin(java.lang.String, android.webkit.ValueCallback<java.lang.Long>)` but methods, that previously allowed to set quota, are deprecated since API 18, so you cannot set/decrease/increase quota in any way right now.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a minimal script for that:
https://github.com/DVLP/localStorageDB

The goal is to have a very simple usage with key - value pairs like in localStorage, and take advantage of large size of IndexedDB and it's potential performance gain thanks to it being asynchronous.

Hope you'll find this useful!