# How much does Android WebView localstorage can store?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, local-storage, android-webview

I know that Chrome's localstorage can only hold up to 5MB. However, Is it also 5MB for Android WebView or is it higher?

I also want to know if there's an easier way of saving javascript objects on Android WebView, How do app developers store datas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9897354/8413748) post. It has a detailed explanation about the WebView Storage.